# Laravel 5.6 Blade using variables within blade function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.6

I have a Blade template that I would like to use from multiple Controllers, as although the DB table is different, everything else is the same.

For example, I have the following line in the template:

`<li><a href="{{ URL::to('manufacturer') }}">View All Manufacturers</a></li>`

I would like to make this dynamic, so I can improve so that it is:

`<li><a href="{{ URL::to('manufacturer') }}">View All {{ name }}</a></li>`

But how do I also apply this to the first part?

Comment: Would I generate the url in the Controller and then just pass the string, perhaps that's considered the best way?

Comment: You have a solution just implement it... I would go the other way tho, 5 controllers - 5 views (or more depending on CRUD).

Comment: Ah, passing the url wouldn't work, because I'm doing a foreach within blade to pass in a parameter for edit url.  You would just copy and paste each view?  Seems like a lot of manual replication

Comment: You need to name your routes and use the name to generate url within your views. In web.php `...get('/manufacturer/{id}'...)->name('manufacturer.edit');` and within view `route('manufacturer.edit', ['id' => $id]);` now you see that string **manufacturer** can be "extracted" and you can do foreaches or whatever, but routes must follow some standard (that you make up). Yes I would copy/paste code around so each controller uses its own views and extract same stuff to the "common" layout. And to answer your question you do it `{{ URL::to($name) }}`.

Comment: Aha, I changed to: `<li><a href="{{ route($name.'.index') }}">View All {{ name }}</a></li>` and that worked a charm, thanks!  Ah ok, so you mean perhaps make this a component (or child) view?

Comment: Depends, I am just working with what you described here, maybe you are doing it correctly, I don't know :). Good luck.

Comment: Thanks man, I've just moved over from CodeIgniter, so open to feedback :).  Feel free to do the above as an answer if you want some points!

Comment: Nah :), delete the question instead, I do not think it has any use besides you. BTW: I once used CI too :), and head over to https://laracasts.com/ and check out some free videos, it will help you a ton.

Comment: OK!  Yea I saw on your profile ;)!  I also checked out a random aviation question out of curiosity!

Answer (score 1):

You have to extend the blade for this.

create a  custom directive for this.

in your `AppServiceProvider`

```
   public function boot()
{


    Blade::directive('myDirective', function ($expression) {
        return "<li><a href=". URL::to($expression).">View All ". ucfirst($expression)."</a></li>";


}
```

And now in your view you can use

```
@myDirective('manufacturer')
it will return your desired input.
```